# Error occurs in inline parsing — so it always throws a CommonMarkException was unhandled by user code in CommonMarkConverter.cs

Tags: c#, .net, exception, markdown, commonmark

My line endings settings are in Windows (CR/LF), but every time I try **to view** the saved markdown document, I get a **commonmarkexception in commommarkconverter.cs.** It told me that there was an error during in-line parsing.

*Maybe what is wrong is in how I save the newly created markdown.*

I also cannot find a decent tutorial about this error online, so I'm putting this here.

Comment: Can you paste the *exact* error message you're receiving, and also the relevant snippet from your code?

Comment: also please post a link to the markdown file, or better yet a minimal example that causes it to fail.